# Display item in blade only if it's not there already in the view

Tags: jquery, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I'm trying to get an item from the database, to only display if it is not already there in the view yet in some other place.

What I have now is that I get an item from the database into a view with a sortable list so that the order can be dragged. Then the list is sorted and the order is saved as json. In the store method the item gets attached to the corresponding json data, so that it can be given back to the same view for display.

The problem is that now the item gets displayed in the right order, but it also displays the original unsorted item, adding the same item on top each time I save the order.

Any ideas to how I can fix this, or if there's a better approach?

```
<form id="serializeForm" action="{{ route('storeConcept', $id) }}" method="post">
{{ csrf_field() }}
  <input id="serialize_output2" type="text" class="form-control" name="serialize">
  <button id="createConceptButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save order</button>
</form>

<ol class='sortableTheme'>
  <!-- Get all items from storage for sorting-->
    @isset($items)
      @foreach($items as $item)
        <li data-id="{{$item->id}}" data-name="{{$item->name}}" data-type="item">
         data
        </li>
      @endforeach
    @endisset

    <!-- Get item order from controller when save button is clicked-->
    @isset($json)
      @foreach($json as $key => $sortable)
        <li data-id="{{$sortable->id}}" data-name="{{$sortable->name}}" data-type="item">
          data
        </li>
      @endforeach
    @endisset
</ol>
```

Edit: added code from my edit view

Comment: What have you tried? Post some code.

Comment: May be better approach is to share some of your code.

Comment: Apologies, I added code from the view. It works, but it adds one on top everytime because it's needed the first time so that it can be manipulated.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it (more like a workaround) by adding an extra ol that is only draggable where I loaded in the saved items. Than those can be dragged into the ol that saves the placement.

```
<ol class='sortableTheme'>
<!-- Get item order from controller when save button is clicked-->
  @isset($json)
    @foreach($json as $key => $sortable)
      <li data-id="{{$sortable->id}}" data-name="{{$sortable->name}}" data-type="item">
      data
      </li>
    @endforeach
  @endisset
</ol>

<ol class="draggable>
   <!-- Get all items from storage for sorting-->
   @isset($items)
   @foreach($items as $item)
     <li data-id="{{$item->id}}" data-name="{{$item->name}}" data-type="item">
      data
      </li>
   @endforeach
 @endisset
</ol>
```